# formatting Data in Kendo grid

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I am having problems formatting date data in the kendo angular 2 grid.

My kendo grid column looks like

```
<kendo-grid-column width="60" title="Time Stamp" field="timeStamp" width="120" format="{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss}"></kendo-grid-column>
```

and the data for the date comes in as 2017-01-24T08:48:15.000-05:00 (with the time stamp). How do I conver it to the above format ?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should parse the string `2017-01-24T08:48:15.000-05:00` into valid JavaScript Date. Then formatting will work as expected.

Quick example - http://plnkr.co/edit/dhKOhdZtr3wfS98LBYsZ?p=preview

Comment: Cool.That works. Just curious, do you have a sample for a grid that gets data from an observable service/behavioral subject ?

Comment: [DataBinding](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/data-binding/data-binding/) and [Editing](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/editing/) examples have quite sophisticated demonstration of binding to observable.